# Не работает HTTP-обработчик

Tags: http, iis, handlers

Задача - для работы с почтой необходимо использовать Outlook REST API.

Взял пример запроса кода авторизации:

```html
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&state=12345
```

Интересует параметр redirect_uri - URI перенаправления приложения, на который можно отправлять ответы проверки подлинности для их получения приложением.

Решил начать с создания простого http-обработчика, нашел инструкцию:
https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/308001/how-to-create-an-asp-net-http-handler-by-using-visual-c-net

1. HTTP-обработчик взял с этого сайта, создал как проект библиотеки классов, добавил ссылку на сборку System.Web.dll для того, чтоб использовать IHttpHandler и HttpContext.
2. В IIS 8.5 настроил обработчик
   Создал новый каталог с именем обработчика C:\Inetpub\Wwwroot\Handler\Bin и скопировал туда MyHandler.dll.
   IIS -> Сайты -> Default Web Site -> добавил виртуальный каталог.
   Просмотр возможностей -> Сопоставление обработчиков -> Добавить сопоставление сценария -> создал сопоставление для расширения *.sync (для тестирования работы обработчика). 
   В поле исполняемый файл ввел следующий путь: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Aspnet_isapi.dll
   В папке Handler создал файл Default.sync.
3. Создался файл Web.config. Добавил в этот файл 
   Получил ошибку:
   Ошибка HTTP 500.23 - Internal Server Error
   Обнаружены значения параметров ASP.NET, которые неприменимы в интегрированном режиме управляемого конвейера.
4. Изменил содержимое web.config.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
   <add path="*.sync" verb="*" type="MyHandler.SyncHandler, Handler" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
        <hiddenSegments>
          <add segment="Extensions" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".sync" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </staticContent>
        <handlers>
            <add name="SYNC" path="*.sync" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" />
        </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Ошибок нет. По инструкции должен вернуться ответ "Hello from custom handler". Сейчас запрос файла Default.sync (http://localhost/Handler/Default.sync) запрашивает разрешение на скачивание.

В целом правильно ли я все делаю?

Comment: Ну так скачайте - и посмотрите ответ, в браузере. И заголовки ответа посмотрите. Видимо заголовки ответа такие, которые трактуются как "нужно скачивать". Возможно ваш браузер не поддерживает rest (или json) - в таких случаях так же предлагается скачать.

Comment: `application/octet-stream` - это на скачивание. Так и должно работать.

Comment: Пусто.
Как изменить web.config, чтобы при запросе файла ответ "Hello from custom handler", который я прописал в HTTP-обработчике, отобразился в браузере, без скачивания?